# Adding module "angular-hotkeys" to my mean.js app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, hotkeys, mean-stack, meanjs

Just getting started with angular - so hoping I am not missing something absolutely obvious.  I am using mean.js (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node stack) and working on a simple to do app to get me started.  I am trying to add the [angular-hotkeys](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys) module to my app.

I installed the module using `sudo npm install -g angular-hotkeys --save`

I then added `ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('cfp.hotkeys');` to my core.client.module.js file.

And in my config.js file, I added cfp.hotkeys as a dependency:

```
var ApplicationConfiguration = (function() {

 // Init module configuration options

 var applicationModuleName = 'taskmanager';

 var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngCookies',  'ngAnimate',  'ngTouch',  'ngSanitize',  'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'cfp.hotkeys'];
```

Finally - I bound hotkeys to my controller:

```
// Lists controller
angular.module('lists').controller('ListsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Lists', 'SelectedList', 'hotkeys',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Lists, SelectedList, hotkeys ) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;

        console.log('hotkeys');
```

But every time I load the page I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: hotkeysProvider <- hotkeys http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$injector/unpr?p0=hotkeysProvider%20%3C-%20hotkeys
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3792:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3920:39)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3797:45
    at getService (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3920:39)
    at invoke (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3947:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:3967:23)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:7260:28
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:6651:34
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:332:20) <section data-ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

I know I am probably doing something very simple wrong - but for the life of me I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be because the module is called `cfp.hotkeys` not `hotkeys`, that mean's you're loading the wrong module name in your file.

See the name of module defined [here](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys/blob/master/build/hotkeys.js)

Update: Install the module using `bower` instead of using `npm` and also not globally.

`bower install angular-hotkeys --save`

Comment: Would I use cfp.hotkeys in my ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule or what I use to pass to the controller? (Or both?)  Thanks!

Comment: Replaced the module name to cfp.hotkeys everywhere I had used hotkeys - no change in the error.

Comment: I would recommend clearing browser cache, also I would recommend you to install it via bower install rather than npm

Comment: and one more thing I just noticed, you are installing your module globally using -g, that wouldn't install the component in your local node_modules folder, you need to install it without the -g flag

Comment: You were right, I backtracked to a stable commit, and then installed it using Bower.  If you update your answer I can mark it as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: I did that, you can verify it.

Comment: Update: right now there are two angular-hotkeys in bower, and if you install with the above line, you'll get the wrong one. for the cfp.hotkeys lib, I needed to do bower install --save chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys